# When install numpy, getting this error 'SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.'

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

I am tring to install numpy with pip3, my environment:ubuntu(WSL), python3.8

```
pip3 install numpy
```

but I get this error

```
# pip3 install numpy
...
 INFO: building library "npyrandom" sources
    INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
    INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/setup.py", line 494, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/setup.py", line 486, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 60, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 34, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 62, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 318, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 507, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 54, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 351, in check_types
        raise SystemError(
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7vewheak-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mx9wlqi4/numpy/
```

I am try to install python-dev|python-devel
`# sudo apt-get install python-dev`
`# sudo apt-get install python-devel`
(python-devel installation occoured another error:E: Unable to locate package python-devel, and I ignore it)

Then I try again to install numpy, error is as the same.

Comment: is it `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` ?. Just try this & let me know.

Comment: I have try "sudo apt-get install python3-dev", it have other dependencies, and I try to solve them, finally, got this: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.2.5-3ubuntu0.7) but 2.2.9-1ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: maybe as it say, my python package is broken? I'll try to install python3.8 later